# Flex 3 Accessing IncludeInLayout in Component Instance

Tags: flex3, components, instance

I've got a Flex 3 question about using includeInLayout with a component instance.

So, to access the instance of my component, I used something like this:

```
var _myCard:Card = this["card"+cardNum];
```

I wanted to "turn-off" the datagrid in the component, so I used bindings on "includeInLayout" and "visible":

```
if(myArray.length == 0){
       _myCard.myBoolean = false;  
       _myCardInstance.myBoolean = false;
    }
```

This worked fine. The dataGrid wasn't visible. But, I was wondering why, I couldn't access the includeInLayout and visible properties directly. Why couldn't I do:

```
_myCard.myGrid.visible = false;   
_myCard.myGrid.includeInLayout = false;
```

Is there a way to do it without bindings? Bindings are fine. I just didn't understand why the above didn't work. I'm trying to learn.

My shortened component is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Panel 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"  layout="absolute" 
    width="500"
    height="400">



    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        public var myBoolean: Boolean = true;

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>



        <mx:Text text="My Text" textAlign="center"/>

        <mx:DataGrid  id="myGrid"    
            y="200"
            dataProvider="{myInitGrid}"
            includeInLayout="{myBoolean}"
            visible="{myBoolean}">

            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="TopicA" headerText="Topic A" width="130"  textAlign="center" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="TopicB" headerText="Topic B"  width="130"  textAlign="center" />                  
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>

</mx:Panel>
```

Thank you!

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with `myGrid.includeInLayout=false;`?

its a read-write [property](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/2/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#includeInLayout).

Comment: Hi Eugene, Thank you for the message. myGrid is in the component, so that won't work in the main application.

Comment: what do you mean by this? are you able to show your final code?